# How to fix shinyapp error which is taking too long to startup?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

My shiny app works fine locally, but when I deploy it on the server ([this app](https://vermaph.shinyapps.io/nypd_crimes_2006-2016/)), it's fetching following error:

[image]

I looked at the logs and it says "out of memory".

[image]

I checked that shiny allows memory usage up to 1 GB for free accounts.

[image]

But when I looked at my app's memory usage it's hardly touching even 500 MB.

[image]

I admit that the CSV file which I am trying to access is of 1.3 GB, possibly can be the culprit.

But I am not convinced because often the good data for analysis are large and doesn't limit to size 2 or 50 MB.

Kindly requesting some expert advice and if possible a workaround.

Comment: Error related to this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037912/5874001

Comment: I've had similar issues before and honestly, I'd avoid having applications relying on large datasets. Would recommend you pull from a dataset via `sqldf` so that you're not loading the entire dataset in your environment.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. The difference is that I upload data files that are 150MB in total. I think the problem is that I use too many libraries that might create this `out of memory!`issue? For my case I use `ballgown RSkittleBrewer genefilter dplyr devtools ggplot2 reshape stringr Gviz`.

Comment: @CorentinD: DId using the thing which you have mentioned solve your error? I am very curious. And what's the solution: is it a line of `code`? I am not able to understand.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess: Umm, I think more than that.

Comment: Nope, I still have the issue, I am wondering if using too many packages is creating the `out of memory!` error because they take too much memory.

Comment: @CorentinD: I am not sure what is your case, if it is possible for you, you can either relax some of your business rules. Like you may aggregate the results which you previously wanted to show. What I would like to do is (1) to check which maximum file size works, (2) divide original app into multiple inter-linked apps such that user would just click and travel to a totally different app for a different type of insight using a different and aggregated metalayer.