# R shiny data limitation

Tags: r, memory-management, shiny

I have a question about the limitation of data in R shiny. I am now working on updating a previous project. The original data is around 5MB and the program would resample the data to obtain an estimate for future values. I am not updating the program to make it more general, where I try to import 300MB data. However, the R shiny would crack. I have used R to handle larger data before. But I am not sure if R shiny has any limitation of data size. Does anyone have any idea about it. Thanks.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037737/how-to-change-maximum-upload-size-exceeded-restriction-in-shiny-and-save-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change 'Maximum upload size exceeded' restriction in Shiny and save user file inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037737/how-to-change-maximum-upload-size-exceeded-restriction-in-shiny-and-save-user)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @PoGibas. I have already adjusted the upload file size, but my question is more about the data manipulation capability with R shiny code. It looks like the program is not able to handle the data more than 300MB? I am not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @cory. I have already adjusted the upload file size, but my question is more about the data manipulation capability with R shiny code. It looks like the program is not able to handle the data more than 300MB? I am not sure why.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What does "crack" mean?

Comment: What all libraries you have used in your project ?

Comment: In free version of shinyapps.io you can have 1GB limit.