# Faster web upload?

Tags: python, r, amazon-ec2, file-upload, shiny

I use a web interface to upload files to AWS. How can I increase the upload speed?

I'm running R Shiny on a `t2.2xlarge` instance and uploading ~50 large CSV files totaling ~500 MB. The slowest part is getting files from my local computer to the web interface instance. Subsequent transfers within AWS are quite fast.

It currently takes me 5-30 minutes to upload files. How do I bring that down to ~2 minutes using Shiny, R, and/or Python?

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 1000*1024^2)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fileInput("test", "Upload here", multiple = TRUE)),
    server = function(input, output, session)
)
```

Edit: this should work from any computer without having to download AWS CLI, etc.

Comment: This might not solve your whole problem but there is a default [upload file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037737/how-to-change-maximum-upload-size-exceeded-restriction-in-shiny-and-save-user) of 5 mb which you'll probably want to change.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I updated my code

Comment: Can you use the AWS CLI to do the upload? It can process files in parallel to make more use of your bandwidth.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein something like that, I just don't know how to make it so that anyone can upload data through the web interface without setting up AWS CLI first